# Web mock does not work with redirect_to in Rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara, webmock

My controller has this piece of code:

```
class MyController < App::BaseController
  def login
    redirect_to 'https://some.api.com/auth?params'
  end
end
```

Of course I don't want to be redirected to external website in tests. So I decided to add webmock gem and add:

`WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)`

To my `spec_helper.rb`.

Inside my feature tests I have:

```
  scenario 'stubbing external api' do
    visit '/connect_to_some_external_api'
    stub_request(:any, /https:\/\/some.api.com\/auth\//)
      .to_return(status: 200, body: 'DUPA. A nawet DUPA123')
    # this works as intended  ->Net::HTTP.get('https://some.api.com/auth/')
    click_link 'Get me to MyController#login'
  end
```

When I call `Net::HTTP.get('https://some.api.com/auth/')` I get response `"DUPA. A nawet DUPA123"`. Which is cool! That means `stub_request` works.

The issue is when user clicks link to `MyController#get` where redirect takes place. It doesn't stub request and just let browser to be redirected to external application.

Is it possible to stub request which comes from controller's `redirect_to`? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In feature tests the requests come from the browser, so you can't mock requests on the server with stub_request. You should verify the redirect in a controller/request spec.  If you really need to test this in a feature test the most flexible solution is to use a programmable proxy like [puffing-billy](https://github.com/oesmith/puffing-billy)